# NET_SFTP not working when doing consecutive logins

Tags: php, phpseclib

the second call doesn't work:

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('domain1', 22);

var_dump($sftp->login('username1', 'password1'));

unset ($sftp);

$sftp2 = new Net_SFTP('domain2', 22);

var_dump($sftp2->login('username2', 'password2'));
```

when i do the second call without the first one, it works perfectly.

this is the error the second call produce:

```
Notice: Invalid HMAC in C:\WT-NMP\WWW\lib\phpseclib\Net\SSH2.php on line 3048
...
Notice: Connection closed by server in C:\WT-NMP\WWW\lib\phpseclib\Net\SSH2.php on line 2015
```

Comment: Maybe post your SSH logs for the second server. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` and then `$ssh->getLog();`.

Answer (score 1):

The library in the question https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/1.0

I could not reproduce the error with v1.0.x-dev "e6a2ce1". It outputs

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

PHP 5.5.37

Please confirm your domains are accessible, passwords are correct, the output remains the same when you change order of domains. Update the question with exact version of the library and php.